# vending machine program php

Tags: php, static, accumulate

so I'm doing this program on php. It's a simple vending machine program, with 3 images.

The logic: Accumulate their prices each click of the image in $total variable. Then, on clicking display total price, it should display the total price.

Mine however displays only the price of one pop. When i click each images twice, it displays only the price of one pop, the first one.?

Here's what i have so far:

```
        $total = 0;

        display_form();

        if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            display_form();

            if(isset($_POST['coke'])) //test for when coke-image is clicked
            {
                $total += 2.00;
            }
            else if(isset($_POST['rootbeer'])) //test for when rootbeer-image is clicked
            {
                $total += 2.00;
            }
            else if(isset($_POST['lemonlime'])) //test for when lemon lime-image is clicked
            {
                $total += 1.00;
            }
            else if(isset($_POST['submit']))
            {
                trackPrice($total);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            display_form(); 
        }

                    function trackPrice($total)
        {
            echo "Your price is $total.";
        }


        function display_form()  //displays actual form
        {
```

Any thoughts? I was planning on putting static on $total? 
Thanks so much.

Comment: You are setting `$total` to zero each time a post is made. You need a way of persisting the total between posts. Either in a session or send the running total with each post.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the code sample you are setting `$total` to zero after each time the form is submitted.

You either need to set the running total in a session so it can be retrieved after each post (better solution)

or

you could add a hidden element in the form that contains the running total and then retrive it with `$_POST["running_total"]` when your form is submitted.

Comment: Using sessions is the best way. Have you read the second part of my answer?

Comment: im getting errors on the second part. i dont know if im implementing it right

Answer (score 2):

As stated before, you should use sessions. Here is a quick example.

```
<?php
    session_start();

    //Select and uncomment either one of the two.
    //1. $_SESSION['total'] = $_SESSION['total'] ?? 0; // PHP 7+;
    //2. $_SESSION['total'] = isset($_SESSION['total']) ? $_SESSION['total'] : 0; // PHP < 7.

    if(!isset($_POST['submit'])){    
        if(isset($_POST['coke'])){ //test for when coke-image is clicked
            $_SESSION['total'] += 2.00;
        } elseif(isset($_POST['rootbeer'])){ //test for when rootbeer-image is clicked
            $_SESSION['total'] += 2.00;
        } elseif(isset($_POST['lemonlime'])){ //test for when lemon lime-image is clicked
            $_SESSION['total'] += 1.00;
        }
    }
?>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
        <label>Total Price: <?php echo $_SESSION['total']; ?></label>
        <input> .... </input>
        <input> .... </input>
        <input> .... </input>
    </form>
```

I've also taken the liberty to change some structure of the code displaying the form (which is something you would always want right?)

Comment: thank you, but out of curiosity, is there a way to not use session?

Comment: Not in a secure way. Cookies, get requests, hidden elements relying on ip to store unique data are all vurnareble to attack. A session is noting more then a cookie referring to a uniqur ID that the server can use to store data in. This is true when you actually care about security which I hope you do.

Comment: hey i actually tried your code, but its kinda weird because whenever i click... total increments by 2 even with lemonlime... and is there an easy way to start a new session using a click of a button?